# What are the possible ways of explaining the limits in cognitive abilities of evolution driven species?

Tags: biology, evolution, races

For a story, I need to find a way to justify the limited cognitive capacities of an entire race that thrives on biomass, capable of eating anything that is inherently biological.

This race is driven by the constant need of improvement, for that, they can evolve pretty quickly by trying to copy other species' DNA, and by pretty quickly we're talking about a matter of a few generation before the trait starts appearing.

They cannibalize, simply because of two reasons, they don't have the abilities to understand the risks, their 'hunger' for biomass and lack of cognitive abilities actually trumps one their aversion to the practise, and since their DNA is everchanging, the risk in itself is lower than any normal race.

They are also extremely short-lived and reproduce in a manner similar to cloning, since, depending on their current DNA set, they could make eggs, breed with another specie or even one of their own. But their instinct is to overwrite any DNA that isn't theirs if their reproduction's method involves another individual.

The problem is, in order to make the fact that they're not simply enslaving the other races and breed them for food due to their capabilities, they simply lack intelligence and are driven by instincts. But in such an evolutionary mindset, a outcome like this over thousands of generations seems unlikely, even downright **impossible.**

So is there any way to justify this ?

Comment: Lack of complex inteligence no make impossible ['farm' other species](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDbqhqrFz_s)

Answer (score 3):

**This sounds like an extinction weapon**

An incredibly aggressive creature with limited intelligence and the ability to copy useful traits from whatever it eats. Furthermore, it's perfectly willing to eat other copies of the same species and then subsume that creature's superior abilities as well. This seems like a creature that was *created* to be released on a planet and then eat everything on the planet before ultimately dying to the fact that in destroyed the entire ecosystem and thus there's nothing to sustain them.

If you showed this to me, I'd say this was created by an advanced race specifically to drop on planets with below civilization-level indigenous species (note that since the creatures are only as strong as the beats they eat, they could be easily defeated by us humans) in order to cleanse the full ecosystem of the planet so that their own ecosystem can be seeded on the planet. In fact, I believe that this is the rough origin story for the Superman villain Doomsday.

Justifying this based on evolution isn't going to be possible - something which can mix and match skills from the creatures it eat requires an aggressive version of internal DNA mixing that can somehow form a universal pattern no matter what the host DNA is and no matter how complex the incoming DNA is. You'd need a supercomputer equivalent to be able to pull something like that off, which begs the question as to why these things aren't intelligent. Especially since intelligence is basically the greatest asset in all of evolution and thus if these creatures eat an intelligent biomass, they'd assimilate it instantly. It would only make sense if these are artificial creatures which have been programmed to *not* become intelligent.

Comment: `the question as to why these things aren't intelligent.` their purpose in life is to eat and shuffle DNA, anything else is parasitical. In humans, 20% of the energy accounts for the brain function. Constant hunger and the metabolism specialized in manipulating proteins will optimize the nervous system of the race towards finding specific food and little anything else

Answer (score 2):

Evolution cannot produce a monster like you propose, and if you create one in a lab, evolution will destroy it (eventually).

For starters, a super-omnivore would consume all possible food sources, reproduce like crazy, cannibalize each other until only one remained, and then starve to death in the wasteland they created. Without intelligence, they would not see this coming and moderate their behavior to prevent it. Even if some did, evolution would favor whichever branch ignored that problem in its drive to be the last one standing.

Natural selection favors species that do one specific thing better than any other species—but the side effect of specialization is that they do everything else worse. Humans are successful, despite being poorly adapted naturally to any particular task, because our intelligence allows us to use tools to adapt ourselves artificially. *Thinking* is the one thing we're unusually good at. Without that, we'd be toast.

Absorbing DNA from prey to get their traits is just not workable. Each trait is typically composed of hundreds to thousands of genes randomly scattered around the genome, all of which must be present (and anything to the contrary *not* present) for it to work correctly. The "vast* majority of evolution's genetic "experiments" result in either no change or non-viability, and that's with just changing one or two genes at a time!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think it is so obvious that they would evolve intelligence? If you look at earth, a high powered brain is very energy intensive and only evolved in a few special situations (relative to say sharp teeth or good hearing). Nature favours quick and easy solutions and intelligence only evolves if there is no easier way to achieve the same ends. Essentially if you creatures can do their thing without being intelligent, then they won't be.